# Set empty variables for jinja2 template values

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a Jinja2 template file that is being used by Ansible to render the actual configuration file. My use case is to use the same templated file and run it manually (using a wrapper python script), use the system environment variables and populate the template file. For example, the following is my template

```
{%- if groups['abc'] is defined -%}
  {#- inventory compatible with smoketest using obsolete cluster cms/sat -#}
  {%- set groupname='abc' -%}
{%- else -%}
  {%- if groups['sat'] is defined -%}
    {#- classic definition in fixed inventory 4.x release -#}
    {%- set groupname='sat' -%}
  {%- else -%}
    {#- first pass definition from 4.x releases -#}
    {%- set groupname='hosts' -%}
  {%- endif -%}
{%- endif -%}
```

And, I render the template using the code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import jinja2
import os

print os.environ
templateLoader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath="./")
templateEnv = jinja2.Environment(loader=templateLoader)
TEMPLATE_FILE = "test.j2"
template = templateEnv.get_template(TEMPLATE_FILE)
outputText = template.render(env=os.environ)  # this is where to put args to the template renderer

print(outputText)
```

But, I get the following error to begin with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    outputText = template.render(env=os.environ)  # this is where to put args to the template renderer
  File "/Users/karthikjayaraman/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/Users/karthikjayaraman/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "./test.j2", line 9, in top-level template code
    {%- if groups['mdc'] is defined -%}
  File "/Users/karthikjayaraman/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 411, in getitem
    return obj[argument]
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'groups' is undefined
```

In this case, how do I set the groups to an empty value (but define it) in the environment variable so that I do not run into the undefined error. I tried the following settings in shell (before running the python script) but still I get this error.

```
export groups=[]
export groups={}
export groups=()
declare -a groups
```

EDIT 1: One interesting thing I found is that when I set export groups={}, I do not see that variable in print os.environ.

Answer (score 0):

> In this case, how do I set the groups to an empty value

You are calling `.render` incorrectly for that situation. The `kwargs` syntax as you have written it will define a `dict` variable named `env` that contains all the environment variables as children.

Based on your question, what you really want is:

```py
outputText = template.render(dict(os.environ.items()))
```

which will promote all the keys in the environment into *top level* jinja2 variables, instead of them living under `env`.

However, that's only half the problem: just pushing a `Dict[str,str]` into Jinja doesn't make it into `Dict[str, Dict[str, str]]` which is what would be required for `groups['abc']` to do what you want.

For that, you're going to have to go one step further and artifically promote environment variables into rich objects:

```
# assuming `export groups="{}"`
outputText = template.render({
    k: json.loads(v) if v.startswith('{') else v
    for k, v in os.environ.items()})
```